# extract sets of characters from boost::array<char, 100>

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, char

So I have initialized a Char array of 100 length, that receives incoming bytes from UDP socket. I can get single character from array like;

```
boost::array<char, 100> recv_buffer_;

std::cout << "1st char of array:>" << recv_buffer_[0] << std::endl;
// or like this;
std::cout << "1st char of array:>" << recv_buffer_.at(0) << std::endl;
```

but I can't figure out how to extract some sets of characters from this array. i.e. if I receive "this is a test" in my recv_buffer_, how can I extract sub characters from index 2 to index 8 i.e. "is is a". Just like in python where you can extract sub-string from a string by simply giving start and end index.

```
>>my_string = "this is a test"
>>print my_string[2:8]
>>is is a
```

I am looking for similar function for boost array char. by at the documentation of boost array, that mentions the use of "operator", but I have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `string`'s constructor.

`string my_string(recv_buffer_.data() + 2, recv_buffer_.data() + 8 + 1);`

Comment: That worked like a charm.  You missed the .data() after recv_buffer_().

Answer (score 2):

Like all standard containers `boost::array` support *iterators*.

To get a range you can use e.g. `recv_buffer_.begin() + 2` as the start, and e.g. `recv_buffer_.begin() + 8` as the end.